# Append URL extension to from action

Tags: php

I have a form which posts to a preset url variable, I'd like to add an extension to that url by using a dropdown selector:

```
  <form class="my-form"  method="POST" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
  <select name="script_to_follow">
  <option value="script1.php">Report 1</option>
  <option value="script2.php">Report 2</option>
  </select>
```

Does anyone know how to add the value selectors as extenstions to the URL, for example if $URL= www.example.com and Report 1 was selected the resulting action would be to post to www.example.com/script1.php

Answer (score 0):

You May have to do this using jQuery:

```
var url = 'www.example.com';
$(".script_to_follow").change(function(){
var selvalue = $(this).val();
url = url + '/' + selvalue;
window.location = url;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using jQuery.

On Submit call a function:

```
var action = $('form.my-form').prop('action');
var selectedOption = $('select[name="script_to_follow"]').val();
$('form.my-form').prop('action', action+'/'+selectedOption;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Use javascript to listen for change events on the `<select>` field, and change the action of the form based on what's been selected. This is what the other answers are suggesting.
2. To you avoid using javascript,  instead of pointing the form towards different php scripts based on the selected value, have a single php script that switches based on the selected value.  So:

`<form class="my-form"  method="POST" action="action.php">
    <select name="script_to_follow">
    <option value="a">Report 1</option>
    <option value="b">Report 2</option>
    </select>`

And then in `action.php` do something like:

```
 switch ($_GET["script_to_follow"]) {
      case "a":
           // contents of script1.php
      case "b":
           // contents of script2.php
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

simply try this 
add id attribute to select box as

```
<select name="script_to_follow" id="script_to_follow">
  <option value="script1.php">Report 1</option>
  <option value="script2.php">Report 2</option>
  </select>
```

now write some jquery codes to change action attribute with change in option

```
<script>
   $('#script_to_follow').change(function(){  // onchange event 
    var url = $('#script_to_follow').val();  // get selected option
    $('form.my-form').prop('action',url);     // replace action attribute
   });

  </script>
```

**Note : do not forget to include jquery script before form**

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```